# How do I execute certain commands dependent on type of input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a `Scanner` set up to ask the user to either input a number or to input *"EXAMPLE"* to use preset numbers. If they input a number, the code is supposed to ask them more questions and then calculate that. That executes perfectly. If the user inputs *"EXAMPLE"*, it is supposed to set the variables to preset numbers and calculate. I can't get the code to work when EXAMPLE was entered. I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source)
    at CarPool.main(CarPool.java:22)
```

This is my code: Sorry if it is so messy.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarPool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //inputs the scanner tool

        float totaldistance;
        float MPG;
        float gasprice;
        float gasused;
        float totalpeople;
        float totalcost;
        //assigns variables

        System.out.printf("Please type the total distance (miles) you are travelling, or type EXAMPLE for an example: ");
        totaldistance = input.nextFloat();
        if (isNan(totaldistance)) { //If the user types EXAMPLE, use preset numbers
            totaldistance = 8;
            MPG = 23;
            gasprice = (float) 2.31;
            totalpeople = 4;
        }  else if (isNumeric(totaldistance)); {
            System.out.printf("Please enter the MPG of your vehicle: ");
            MPG = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.printf("Pleas enter the price of gas currently: $");
            gasprice = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.printf("Please enter how many people will be splitting the cost of gas:");
            totalpeople = input.nextFloat();
            //Prompts the user for some info that it can use for it's calculations. Sets them as floats for decimal numbers.
        }
        gasused = (totaldistance / MPG); //This finds how much gas the person is using by dividing the distance travelled by the mpg
        totalcost = gasused * gasprice; //This calculates how much you will spend by multiplying the gas you use by the price of gas, given by the user
        totalcost = totalcost / totalpeople; //splits the final cost amongst however many people are chipping in
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$" + "#0.00"); //Formats the price to two decimal places
        System.out.println(formatter.format(totalcost)); //prints the final results
    }

    private static boolean isNumeric(float totaldistance) {
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isNan(float totaldistance) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm having issues at line 22.

Comment: I have already tried several different data types and I get the same error or completely different ones.

Comment: Why should the Scanner class read "EXAMPLE" if you explicitly ask for a float `input.nextFloat()`? Use `input.next()` instead and handle that String instead. Use `Float.parseFloat(userinput)` to convert it. Btw: this `} else if (isNumeric(totaldistance)); {` is not correct. A character is too much, but I guess you can find out which one :).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you will get a mismatch exception because if user enters examples you are reading it as float now you tell me can java convert example into float. no right??

So why dont you read the input data as string and check if it is example then use your preset values otherwise if it float use then accordingly

I think you should get my point.

cheers